# How to target specific user role?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

I got a piece of code which is working, but not targeting wholesale customers. How do I fix it? I tried with "wp get current user, but no effect.

```
/**
 * Adjust the quantity input values
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (in_array('wholesale_customer',$user->roles)) {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        $args['input_value']    = 2;    // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
    }
    $args['max_value']  = 80;   // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = 2;    // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 2;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' ); // Variations

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    $args['max_qty'] = 80;      // Maximum value (variations)
    $args['min_qty'] = 2;       // Minimum value (variations)
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://3v4l.org/Zf0Ep

Comment: No? Could you please change the code so that its working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using this logic in multiple locations it is probably best to move this to a dedicated function, feel free to rename it as you see fit.

```php
function martijn__is_wholesale_customer()
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    return in_array('wholesale_customer', $user->roles, true);
}
```

Then, in your code just wrap your logic in a call to that function:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args($args, $product)
{
    if (martijn__is_wholesale_customer()) {
        if (is_singular('product')) {
            $args['input_value'] = 2;    // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
        }
        $args['max_value'] = 80;   // Maximum value
        $args['min_value'] = 2;    // Minimum value
        $args['step'] = 2;    // Quantity steps
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation'); // Variations

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation($args)
{
    if (martijn__is_wholesale_customer()) {
        $args['max_qty'] = 80;      // Maximum value (variations)
        $args['min_qty'] = 2;       // Minimum value (variations)
    }

    return $args;
}
```

If the above doesn't work, it is possible that you have an incorrect role name. In your theme temporarily add this somewhere obvious, switch to a wholesale role, and inspect to make sure it is spelled correctly.

```php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
var_dump($user->roles);
```